# Generating a preprocessor error if a define is used

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible with the C++ preprocessor to emit an `#error` if a particular `#define` is used? Something like this:

```
#define this_must_not_be_used #error You shouldn't use that.
```

Comment: `#ifdef this_must_not_be_used #error You shouldn't use that. #endif`?

Comment: Yes and no... you can't define a macro that includes a pre-processor directive (`#error`), but if the goal is to trap programmers who accidentally (or otherwise) use `this_must_not_be_used` in their code, then the above will "work" because the compiler will throw an error anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard way of defining a macro in such a way that its use, wherever it is, will give you a compilation error, especially not one that gives a clear and useful error message. For all you know, the code that uses it might just be stringizing its result, or it might be part of an `assert` condition that gets removed by the preprocessor.

For most practical purposes, putting something that cannot possibly be part of a valid C (or C++) program will be good enough.

Some implementations do have implementation-specific methods of achieving exactly what you ask for, though. For instance, with GCC, you can use

```
#pragma GCC poison this_should_not_be_used
```

where its subsequent use, no matter how it ends up used, will give:

```
error: attempt to use poisoned "this_should_not_be_used"
```

You may want to look at your own compiler's documentation to see if it has anything similar. You can also use conditional macro definitions, so that with GCC you use this approach, with your compiler you use your compiler's approach, and with an unknown compiler you fall back to the standard method of providing a macro definition that will probably lead to a difficult-to-read error message.

Answer (score 7):

In C++11,

```
#define this_must_not_be_used static_assert(false, "You shouldn't use that.");
```

In C11,

```
#define _Static_assert(0, "You shouldn't use that.");
```

For C before C11 or C++ before C++11, you'll have to think up some other invalid expression that contains a string that will show up in the error message. I'm thinking along the lines of

```
#define this_must_not_be_used ("You shouldn't use that",)
```

Comment: I see where you're going with the `static_assert`, but in many cases, this leads to crazy syntax errors, not the expected clear and useful error message. For example, `if (this_must_not_be_used) { f(); }` gives "error: expected primary-expression before 'static_assert'" with GCC, or "error: expected expression" with clang.

Comment: C11 has a macro `static_assert` which expands to `_Static_assert`. You don't need to use the keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like follows:

```
#ifdef this_must_not_be_used
#error "You shouln't use that."
#endif
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is after. Rather, if *later* code ends up using `this_must_not_be_used`, that later code should get an error.

Answer (score -1):

If the define is used in an assignment, then the

```
#define this_must_not_be_used static_assert(false, "You shouldn't use that.");
```

will not print the error, but merely give a syntax error.

Instead do the following:

```
#define this_must_not_be_used 0; static_assert(false, "You shouldn't use that.");
```

This way you will get the message printed at compile time if the defined is assigned to a variable (it will generate a compile error no matter what).

Comment: Still not syntactically valid in many situations though. I think you would need to use GCC's statement expressions to get it right. But then if you're already relying on GCC, just use `poison`.

Comment: @Timmmm Correct, but I prefer this solution for compilers that don't support `poison` as it prints the error in plain text in case it is an assignment, and fails gracefully giving a compilation error regardless, as needed to prevent the define from being used.